# Rails 3:Deploy Rails 3 Application in Apache Server on Windows Machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache

I have a Rails Application which runs on `"thin"` Server on Windows Machine. I heard the best Server for Rails is `Phusion Passenger`,but unfortunately my Server runs on Windows Machine and it is not possible to install Phusion Passenger in windows.

Is it possible to deploy my Rails Application in Apache Server. If possible will it effect the performance of my Rails Application.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache to reverse proxy requests to the thin server. The apache configuration directives look a little like this (you will probably need to change these)

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/rails/public

<Location /assets >
  ProxyPass !
</Location>

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

Replace 3000 with the port you set thin to run on.